# How can I embed the swf file into asp page?

Tags: asp.net, html

I am using the following code but it does not work:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width="540" height="400" hspace="10">
    <param name=movie value="http://servername/foldername/file.swf">
    <param name=quality value=high><param name="LOOP" value="false">
    <embed src="C:\Users\SAINI\Desktop\online\spn_20Dec\vp\images\abc.swf"
           width="540" height="400" hspace="10" loop="false" 
           quality=high
           pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" 
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    </embed> 
</object>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Apple safari, Mozila Firefox and ...
you need a code which work in all of them and there it is:

```
<object width="900" height="400" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" id="myMovieName" >
            <param name="src" value="YOUR MOVIE ADDRESS HERE.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="autohigh" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="black" />
            <param name="autostart" value="true" /> 
            <param name="FlashVars" value="init=yes&check=true" />
            <param src="flash/movie.swf" autostart="true" flashvars="init=yes&check=true" 
                quality="autohigh" bgcolor="#000000" name="myMovieName"/>
</object>
```

All you need to do is:

1. copy and paste this code into your project,
2. change the address to your clip address,
3. change the dimensions of clip (in first line)
4. Enjoy it!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code and it works with me without any alteration except the file and its location. I placed the file inside the root of my website. Sadly it doesn't work when I place another location. I don't know the reason yet

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=5,0,0,0" width="540" height="400" hspace="10">
    <param name=movie value="http://servername/foldername/file.swf">
    <param name=quality value=high><param name="LOOP" value="false">
    <embed src="xx.swf" width="540" height="400" hspace="10" loop="false" quality=high pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    </embed> </object>
```